# AutoComplete is not a function with jQuery 3.4.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have add jquery-3.4.1 and jquery-ui.1.12.1, but autocomplete not a function. What wrong?[image]

Comment: Are you also loading another version of jQuery.js below what is shown? If so would wipe out the jQueryUI methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the higher versions of the JQuery UI library like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have jQuery 3.3.1 and the last jquery-ui version and works. Try with last versions. Look the image:

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7tzZ.png)